# Glassfish EJB 3 OpenJPA 2

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place at the moment with this problem. If I define my persistence context as:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistentUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Glassfish refused to start with the error:

```
SEVERE: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [com.ckd.business.MusicService/entityManager] in the scope of the module called [home]. Please verify your application.
```

But if I changed the declaration to:

```
e@PersistenceContext(name = "persistentUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Glassfish is able to deploy my WAR file but when I load the page up I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
```

What the heck?! I have saved the **persistence.xml** file to **WEB-INF\classes\META-INF** directory as per the requirement and saw that Glassfish has loaded JPA properly. But it doesn't matter what I do, Glassfish always fail. I'm using **Glassfish 3.1 OpenSource Edition**.

Does anyone know of a solution or a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but some thoughts:

I think the first is the correct usage. The `unitName` must be the same as in your persistence.xml. There should be something like this

```
<persistence-unit name="persistentUnit">
 ...
</persistence-unit>
```

As seen in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727920/injecting-entity-manager-into-managed-bean), remember that injection takes place after the constructor.

Hope this helps to get a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I already have **name="persistentUnit"** specified in the **persistence.xml** file. Eventually, I had to remove Glassfish server from the hard drive, re-download it and start again. It seems to work now. I'm stumped though why Glassfish did not report that it's not working - even a line in the log file would have helped - but nothing. Arrg, it was so frustrating.