# EJB always null in service

Tags: java, service, jersey, ejb

I am a rookie in services and now I am finding an issue when injecting my EJB on it, it always comes null. I saw people with this issue in several posts as well, new or olds, but the solutions that was proposed by them either didn't work or I didn't know how to implement it.

I am using tomcat v7 + jersey implementation v1.8.

The solutions that I tried so far:

1. Use spi injection, as result, the instance was there, but the my EntityManager was always null;
2. Making the service @Stateless, always got null as well;
3. Add transaction attribute [like this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777691/2551648), still null coming;
4. Last one I didn't knew how to implement, [it is in this post in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3029185/6346585), to implement a provider

The Facade that I am trying inject is this one that I made:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class AutoEntityFacade extends EntityFacade {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myauto-unit")
    private EntityManager manager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        setEntityManager(manager);
    }

}
```

My service class is also quite simple, but the injection is not working properly:

```
import br.com.aes.myauto.model.exception.HttpBusinessException;
import br.com.aes.myauto.model.person.Person;
import br.com.aes.myauto.service.facade.AutoEntityFacade;
import br.com.aes.myauto.service.facade.EntityFacade;
import br.com.aes.myauto.service.rest.CrudService;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

@Path("/person")
@Stateless
public class PersonService extends CrudService<Person> {

    @QueryParam(value = "name")
    private String name;
    @QueryParam(value = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @QueryParam(value = "email")
    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void setup() throws HttpBusinessException {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
            addParameter("name", "%" + name + "%");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName)) {
            addParameter("lastName", "%" + lastName + "%");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(email)) {
            addParameter("email", "%" + email + "%");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String buildQuery() {
        return "select obj from Person obj " + getQuery();
    }

    @Override
    protected String buildCountQuery() {
        return "select count(obj) from Priority obj " + getQuery();
    }

    private String getQuery() {
        boolean firstClause = true;
        String result = "";
        String connector = "and";

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
            if (firstClause) {
                result += "where ";
                firstClause = false;
            } else {
                result += connector;
            }
            result += " obj.name like :name ";
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName)) {
            if (firstClause) {
                result += "where ";
                firstClause = false;
            } else {
                result += connector;
            }
            result += " obj.lastName like :lastName ";
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(email)) {
            if (firstClause) {
                result += "where ";
                firstClause = false;
            } else {
                result += connector;
            }
            result += " obj.email like :email ";
        }

        return result;
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myauto-unit")
    private EntityManager manager;

    @EJB
    private AutoEntityFacade entityFacade;

    @Override
    protected EntityFacade getEntityFacade() {
        return entityFacade;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return manager;
    }

}
```

Is there anything that I am missing?
This is my project structure:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4PKZ.png)

As you can see, I also provided the beans on both web and service layer. In my service I have a test class, so I know that jersey is working properly and accepting the parameters.

What am I missing here?

---

I changed the container to see if I could have any more detailed exception, since tomcat wasn't being that helpful, these are the results, which I still can't find out.

```
Warning: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:454)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2547)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1899)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy253.getBusinessObjectById(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.aes.myauto.service.crud.__EJB31_Generated__PersonService__Intf____Bean__.getBusinessObjectById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:726)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:534)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$ComponentProcessorFactoryImpl.get(WebApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.get(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.init(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:133)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:526)
    ... 54 more

Warning: StandardWrapperValve[MyAuto REST Service]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet MyAuto REST Service threw exception
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$ComponentProcessorFactoryImpl.get(WebApplicationImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.get(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBInjectionInterceptor.init(EJBInjectionInterceptor.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:133)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:526)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:95)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:724)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:247)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:449)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2547)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1899)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy253.getBusinessObjectById(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.aes.myauto.service.crud.__EJB31_Generated__PersonService__Intf____Bean__.getBusinessObjectById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at last I found a way to do so that isn't that bad.

The way I did to make it work is probably known by most, (even myself, shame on me), but due the scenario, it didn't seemed to be the best approach.

I recreated some parts of my system in which I could eliminate the EJB and stay with the EntityManager only, having that done, the EJB or persistenceContext was also not viable, so I created a new entityManagerFactory and that did the trick.

```
private EntityManager manager;
private EntityManagerFactory emf  = null;

public PersonService() {
    if (manager == null){
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myauto-unit");
        manager = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Not complicated to be implement and easy to perform the test.

Cheers